# My laptop takes ages to startup, after recent format. Whats up?

Tags: windows, format, boot, lag, reinstall

After a boot sector crash, I formatted my hard drive and reinstall Windows 7 from scratch.

Although my laptop now takes ages to startup (about 10-15mins!) and after I'm logged in, everything lags!

This started after I rebooted my system for first time, after Windows installation and after some updates were downloaded and installed. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: My laptop model is: Samsung np-r519 and Im using: Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit

Comment: I think this is a question for Superuser, as it does not seem to contain any questions about programming in general

Answer (score 4):

I have seen it with very old Dell PC stations, getting new HDD helped.

Answer (score 3):

Your hard drive is currently in the process of failing. The very long read times are likely because it is seeking for an extraneous amount of time due to either a damaged or badly off voice coil or a damaged platter resulting in difficulty locating tracking cylinders.

**Immediately copy all of your important data off of the drive**. It may fail entirely shortly and with no warning. In some cases, performing a thorough wipe of the drive (such as a Gutmann wipe) may actually restore functionality (I don't understand why), but I wouldn't trust this to last. **Purchase a replacement drive, they're not very expensive.**

Comment: ^^ Take the above advice.  Next, download one of the many free bootable OS on a CD, and see if boot time is dramatically different.  This will (mostly) separate your concern -- is it HDD, or is it laptop?  Have you run a drive checker?  Some bootable OS CDs have techy utilities you can run to check out the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like HDD problems.
There are many software for troubleshooting these kind of things.
You can try [HDDScan](http://hddguru.com/software/2006.01.22-HDDScan/) which is a freeware and rather good at finding problems with the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You might start it from a live CD/USB. A live OS won't touch your HDD, won't install anything but it might contain the tools to recover/examine the errors like HDD corruption or memory defect.

You can give a try:

*Hiren's Boot CD
 *Ultimate Boot CD
 * and many more..